# Is there a way in MySQL to reverse a Boolean field with one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my table titled 'authorised'. Its default is 0. It needs to be changed to 1 when the user is authorised, but it must be able to be reset to 0. I know I could do this easily with two queries like so:

```
$authorised = Db::query('SELECT authorised FROM users WHERE id=2');

$newAuthValue = ($authorised['authorised']) ? 0 : 1;

Db::query('UPDATE users SET authorised=' . $newAuthValue . ' WHERE id=2');
```

Is there a way to do this with one query? To reverse a Boolean value?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
UPDATE users SET `authorised` = IF (`authorised`, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Just make sure you add your where clause, alex.

Comment: SET `authorised` = NOT `authorised`

Answer (score 42):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `authorised` = NOT `authorised` WHERE id = 2
```

This query will also work to negate the field, and is more inline with boolean syntax.

Comment: Ok, that didn't get posted properly, those slashes should be backticks, which are MySQLs default encapsulator.

Comment: SET authorised = !authorised

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to do this, and here's a simple one:

```
UPDATE users SET authorised = ABS(authorised - 1) WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: Whoops, missed that. Thanks Chad.

Comment: why not just "1 - authorised" ?

Comment: @nickf: I agree with you, the following should work: UPDATE users SET authorised = 1 - authorised WHERE id = 2;

Comment: Yep, that way will work just as well. There's no reason I went with the ABS() method, it's just the one that I thought of first. :b

Answer (score 4):

It’s also possible to use XOR if your 'boolean' field is implemented as a TINYINT:

```
UPDATE users SET authorised = authorised XOR 1 WHERE id = 2;
```

This will set 'authorised' to 0 if currently 1, and to 1 if currently 0. It will also zeroise all non-zero values, so it is an ideal solution if you (like me) use several positive values to reflect a variety of 'on' levels, but always need to revert to 0 when 'off'.