# Query to toggle a Boolean value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Is there a way in MySQL to reverse a Boolean field with one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665002/is-there-a-way-in-mysql-to-reverse-a-boolean-field-with-one-query)

To update a (Boolean) value, normally we would check if it's set to false or true, and update it. Is there a query that would toggle a Boolean value?

Comment: Are you talking about a tinyint field?

Comment: I am really annoyed, who's downvoting me, if my solutions are really annoying then why don't you give an explanationi

Comment: @experimentX If you're being serially downvoted by the same person, there are scripts that run periodically which detect such behaviour and adjust things accordingly.

Comment: @middaparka i think i should contact administrator do you know how to contact

Comment: @experimentX You should be able to flag this question and leave a note to a mod.

Comment: @experimentX You can email team@stackoverflow.com I believe. However, you might want to flag this question (or one of the other ones) first, or perhaps open a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and see what sort of response you get there first.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytbl
   SET field = !field
 WHERE id = 42
```

Where `42` is the `id` of the record, `field` is the name of the Boolean field and `mytbl` is the table name.

Comment: +1 for zerky! You can also use `NOT` if you prefer that :)

Answer (score 16):

You can use a *Boolean operator* for this. Here *delete* is your Boolean field.

```
update tab set `delete`=NOT `delete`
```

Comment: thanks but first gets accepted +1

Comment: This solution also works for none boolean fields such as int and tinyint where values are set to 0 or 1.