# I need to change $mode value 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I do not know how to do that:

```
function test(){
    include_once 'api/db.php';
    include_once 'api/users.php';

    $devices_dep = "devices";

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();


    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

    $device_mode = ???;

    $sqlQuery = "UPDATE $devices_dep SET device_mode=$device_mode WHERE id=$id";

    $db->query($sqlQuery);
}
```

```
$device_mode = ($device_mode == 1 ? 0 : 1);
```

I realized that this is not correct. I don't have any ideas...

Comment: No. I need to write this in PHP.

Comment: What are you talking about? You just need to adjust your query `$sqlQuery`

Comment: Please be warned that your `UPDATE` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: If you reeeaallly need to toggle the value in php, then you need to pick up the value of `device_mode` from the database first with a `SELECT` statement, and then toggle the value, and then run your `UPDATE` statement. But this is a very inefficient way to do it. @DarkBee has a good point - use an PHP+SQL statement that toggles the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has already been pointed out in comments, you don't need to do it "in PHP", because you can do it directly in the query by means of negating the value, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912959/2054918) ([by DarkBee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74357423/i-need-to-change-mode-value-0-to-1-and-1-to-0-in-database/74357657#comment131270291_74357423)).

In case, for whatever reason, you're dealing specifically with integers, but not Booleans, and you're still guaranteed to have only 1's and 0's in that column, your new value in the query could look like `device_mode = 1 - device_mode`, which swaps 1s and 0s.

You could still do it directly in PHP by first fetching a row from the database and modifying it accordingly, but I'm almost 100% sure that's not what you need, unless you anyway need to somehow process the entry in  another way also.